# How do I create a directory inside the directory where my .cpp file is placed?

Tags: c++, directory, working-directory

I am creating a directory in the desktop folder using this code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <direct.h>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
string k,s="c:/Users/Dell/Desktop/";
cin>>k;
string p =s+k;
    if (mkdir(p.c_str()) != 0)
    {
       cerr<<"Failed"<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But this code will be specific to my pc only as it has the whole parent directory path.
I want to create a new folder inside my working directory where the main.cpp is placed, because we don't know where the user will place the cpp file.
I know there are a lot of solutions similar to this problem on the forum but I couldn't find or understand any that could help me here. Thanks.

Comment: You can get the path of the current source file using the `__FILE__` macro. It's not guaranteed to be a full path though,  And using the same directory as the source file doesn't make sense anyway, especially if you want to be able to distribute your program and install it on systems where the source file isn't even available.

Comment: You'll probably either want to use the working directory or read the user directory for the user running the program or the value of the `USERPROFILE` environment variable (assuming Windows as target system).

Answer (score 1):

Do you really mean the .cpp file?

You can get the filename as a string using the `__FILE__` macro and then use `std::filesystem::path` to manipulate it, but are you sure this is really what you want to do? Are you expecting end users to compile this program in the location they want to run it?

You can also (in theory) get the path through which the program was executed using the `argv` argument to main, which seems more likely to be what you mean, but it's unreliable in a number of surprising ways ...